# add value to column within a data frame only for a subset

Tags: r

I have a data frame, called APD, and I would like to assign a value to the column "Fitted_voltage", but only for a specific subset (grouped by serial_number). How do I do that?
In the following example I want to assign 150 for the Fitted_Voltage but only for the Serial_number 913009814.

```
Serial_number Lot Wafer Amplification Voltage Fitted_Voltage
912009913 9 912 1878 375.3 NA
912009913 9 912 1892 376.8 NA
912009913 9 912 1900 377.9 NA
812009897 8 812 3931.1 370.5 NA
812009897 8 812 3934.8 371 NA
812009897 8 812 3939.9 372.3 NA
...
...
```

Finally I would like to do this automatically. I fit some data points and want to assign to each serial_number the fitted result.
The process could be:

Fit via function function_to_observe and do point-wise inverse regression at a specific value of 150 for serial number 912009913:

```
function_to_observe(150)
```

This yields the result

```
[1] 360.6395
```

which shall be stored in the data frame in the column Fitted_Voltage for one single serial_number

Then the next serial_number 812009897 will be fitted and this value shall be stored for it and again and again..

I know I can add the value to the column, but not limited to the subset:

```
APD["Fitted_Voltage"] <- Fitted_voltage<- function_to_observe(150)
```

**Update:** According to Eric Lecoutre answer I have now:

```
ID<- 912009913
ID2<- 912009914

APD_result<- data.frame(Serial_Number=rep(c(ID, ID2),each=1), Fitted_Voltage=NA)

comp <- tapply(APD_result$Fitted_Voltage, APD_result$Serial_Number, function_to_observe =  inverse((function(x=150) exp(exp(sum(x^0*VK[1],x^1*VK[2],x^2*VK[3],x^3*VK[4])))), 50, 375))

APD_result$Fitted_Voltage = comp[APD_result$Serial_Number]
```

This works very well but I need to apply some minor changes. Which are not so minor for me..

1.) The Serial_numbers have to be added automatically (given as two examples "ID, ID2")

2.) I do not get tapply to run since I removed Voltage. Sorry for not specifying this in my previous question. The voltage is not of interest, I only want Serial_number and Fitted_Voltage in the end frame, which belong to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear for me what your `function_to_observe` does. I assume you "exploits" the set of Voltage values for a given `Serial_Number`.

I prepared a small function that does so having an additional argument (value).

Does the following answer your question?

```
df <- data.frame(Serial_Number=rep(c("a","b"),each=3),Voltage=abs(100*rnorm(6)), FittedVoltage=NA)
function_to_observe <- function(vec,value=150) {mean(vec)+value}
comp <- tapply(df$Voltage, df$Serial_Number, function_to_observe, value=150)
df$FittedVoltage = comp[df$Serial_Number]
```

Having as

```
result

  Serial_Number   Voltage FittedVoltage
1             a  21.01196      205.4419
2             a  37.04815      205.4419
3             a 108.26565      205.4419
4             b 121.37657      264.3040
5             b  39.92053      264.3040
6             b 181.61485      264.3040
```

(yeah I know fitted voltage here is totally unrelated to  voltage... Just does not understand what your 150 does here)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks as what I'm looking for. At the moment the data structure for creating the data frame is not completely ready but I think changes will be adjustable for me. Therefore thanks a lot again!

Comment: Ah, one thing is not clear for me: How do I put in the varying serial numbers? You wrote it as "rep(c("a","b"). In my case there are hundred of serial numbers so I should pass them somehow automatically. Can you figure this out again, please? Thank you!

Comment: I have some probems to "adjust"..  can you also please have a look at my update?

Comment: You don't have to manage ID but start from your initial data.frame APD. `tapply` will automatically take into account all the distinct values for serial numbers. You can then build your output data.frame as the last step I am doing based on APD directly.